# Feedback coming from gas pedal on 14 ' Audi S4 (B8.5)

Tags: audi, pedals

Sometimes I feel some sort of internal feedback coming from gas pedal. It is a really interesting feeling that is hard to explain, almost as if a piece of thick wire is rubbing on the inside of the pedal. It also resembles what those haptic feedback console controllers do.

Is this normal and what is it anyways?

Comment: You're not leaving the cruise control on and forgetting about it, right?

Comment: Hopefully not, is it bad for my car if I do by accident?

Comment: No - it's just the only time I've ever felt the gas pedal push back is when I accelerate while the cruise is on and then slow back down forgetting that I never canceled the cruise (it only cancels when you press the brake).  The pedal starts moving to keep the car at the cruise speed and it feels squirmy and weird.  Totally doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: I've seen that too, but that is a different feel. The pedal does not push, it vibrates instead.

Comment: [You're not the only one](http://www.audiworld.com/forums/s4-b8-platform-discussion-134/spring-like-vibration-accelerator-pedal-2838151/), but no answers over there either.

Comment: Does it occur during extreme circumstance or normal everyday driving? I was thinking it might be feedback from the traction or stability control, but I figured you'd mention if it only happened when you were hoonin' around an empty parking lot.

Comment: That is odd I'd assume it would just be a plastic pedal assembly with two Accelerator Position Sensors in a housing and a return spring type deal.

Comment: It happens absolutely randomly. But more often, when you begin moving.

Comment: Hard to tell from your explanation. Does it happen only when you push the pedal to the floor?

Comment: No, it happens when I barely touch it. JPhi has provided a link where many people describe exact same experiences but no answer.